# Getting 400 Error when i want to post a file and and string with ApiController Asp.Net Core

Tags: javascript, c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

i tried to send a post with i IFormFile and a string to my ApiController but im getting 400 error, when i send the file alone it works well but when i want to send the string im getting 400 error
even when i just want to send string i get 400 error

My Javascript :

```
    let avatarModel = new FormData();

    avatarModel.set("file", blob);
    avatarModel.set("productId", productId.value);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.open('POST', '/Api/Admin/UploadProductImageForEdit', true);
    xhr.send(avatarModel);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = async function () {

        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        }
    }
```

My ApiController :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UploadProductImageForEdit")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public IActionResult UploadProductImageForEdit(IFormFile file, string productId)
    {
        //..//

        return Ok();

    }
```

[image]

--Update

i found out that it says that my productId field is is null but i don't know why, i even putted manual value for it

[image]
[image]
[image]

thanks for your time

i want to send a IFormFile and a string to my ApiController with method post and not getting 400 error

Comment: So what do you see when you follow the request with the debugger? Specifically, what is in the file data, and what is the value of productId?

Comment: the only things that i get is the 400 error, bad request, and the value of file is a image and the value of product id is just a number that i want to send it as string like "22" and in server i want to upload the image with product id so it's important to me to be able to send the product id, and i did this before in one of my another projects exactly like this but here im getting 400 error, im thinking that maybe i activated an extra security setting, is it possible?

Comment: Pls set the breakpoint and share us more error details.

Answer (score 0):

well, after some research and looking some projects i decided to add [FromFile] behind the productId and it worked, i don't know why it can recieve file without [FromFile] but can't do the same with productId but anyways,

here it is

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("UploadProductImageForEdit")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public IActionResult UploadProductImageForEdit(IFormFile file, [FromForm] string productId)
    {
        ...
    }
```